# How do Python lambda capture semantics work for function pointers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Basically, in the example below, why do the lambdas in `f2` capture a reference to the list comprehension loop variable, but those in `f3` "capture" (really, they just accept an argument) "the way we expect" lambda capture to work?

```
f1 = [lambda x: x, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x + 2]
print([f(0) for f in f1])
f2 = [lambda x: f(x) + 1 for f in f1]
print([f(0) for f in f2])
f3 = [(lambda ff: lambda x: ff(x) + 1)(f) for f in f1]
print([f(0) for f in f3])
```

The three lines outputted are:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: note:  I took the liberty of tagging Python 3 because you rely on the list comp function scope in this code.

Comment: There are *no pointers in Python*. There are only objects, and the semantics work the same for all object types.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Comment: So note, the behavior you see here isn't unique to lambda functions,but would work the same way with free variables using an equivalent `def` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python closures always capture variables, not objects.

In `f2`,

```
f2 = [lambda x: f(x) + 1 for f in f1]
```

all lambdas in the list capture the `f` variable, not the object the variable refers to at the time the lambda is defined. At the end of the comprehension, `f` refers to the last function in `f1`, so all lambdas in `f2` find that function when they look up `f`.

In `f3`

```
f3 = [(lambda ff: lambda x: ff(x) + 1)(f) for f in f1]
```

each call to `(lambda ff: lambda x: ff(x) + 1)` creates a new local `ff` variable, and each `lambda x: ff(x) + 1` captures a different `ff` variable. Unlike `f`, the `ff` variables are never reassigned, so the `lambda x: ff(x) + 1` functions each see a different value of `ff`.

Comment: This object-variable was the distinction I was looking for -- are there any relevant docs I could read on this? It seems that the argument `(f)` in the `f3` example gets passed by "object value", so then `ff` becomes a variable with the corresponding object value from `f1`.

Comment: @VF1: There are the [Python execution model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html), and the [original closure PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/). [Ned Batchelder's writeup on Python variable and assignment semantics](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) may also be useful, particularly the part about how function arguments are passed.

Answer (score 4):

`f` is the same variable throughout the list comprehension. A simpler example:

```
>>> fs = [lambda: x for x in [1, 2]]
>>> fs[0]()
2
```

One common hack to work around this without the extra lambda wrapper is to use a default (as defaults are evaluated when the function is), but that can be confusing to those new to the idiom and you should generally split it out into a new function instead.

```
>>> fs = [lambda x=x: x for x in [1, 2]]
>>> fs[0]()
1
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I'm aware that the comprehension has the same variable - I'm asking why `f3` "works".

Comment: @VF1: In `f3`, `ff` is not the same variable each time. It’s not even a variable in the same function – you have as many `(lambda ff: …)`s as elements in `f1`, and each time they’re called they create a scope with a `ff`, which becomes part of the `lambda x: ff(x) + 1` closure. In other words: `f2` has one variable `f` shared by every `lambda`; `f3` has *n* variables `ff`, each associated with a different `lambda`.

Answer (score 3):

In the second example, `f` is a free variable in the lambdas in `f2` which is bound into their enclosing scope (the list comprehension). The functions take `f`'s value at the time they are called.    The functions in `f2` are called in the following print statement, at which point `f` is already the third lambda from `f1`.
Note that `f` is never in the scope in which `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are defined (presumably global or some broader function scope), but the lambdas always reference their enclosing scope which contains `f`.

In contrast, `ff` is a parameter in the outer lambdas `f3`, but it is bound in the call to those outer lambdas, which happens in the list comprehension that defines `f3`.

Comment: @chepner Right, but the lambda's scope is the list comprehension's scope.  The lambda keeps that scope alive.

Comment: Rereading what I wrote, I think it was correct, but I've added a bit more discussing the list comprehension scope